# Multiple Powerpoint files Playlist functionality in VB?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, vbscript, playlists

My goal is to be able to play back a set of separate Powerpoint .pptx files stored within a directory via a form of playlist which will define the order of files.

Assuming this is only possible via VB Script using an array that lists the filenames and initiates playback from within a master PPT that would always be the first file, or saved as a PPS.

Any feedback or guidance gratefully received, many thanks in advance.

Comment: Powershell is your friend: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13650968/powershell-scipt-to-open-power-point-and-play-slide-show